# How do you spell check JSP files in your application?

Tags: java, perl, jsp, unix, spell-checking

I need to run spell check on jsps in our enterprise apps. I want the spell checker to ignore the html/css/javascript/jsp/java keywords and check on regular English labels. Is there an API or Perl/Unix script way of doing this? I don't want to open each jsp in MS-Word to do that check.

Comment: I want to run the spell check during build and not in IDE. A folder having more than 300 jsps need to be spell checked during build.

Answer (score 1):

If use have free time, I think better way is to write your own spell checking tool.

Please check out following link.
[How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

That article has implemented a spell checker in Python.

Also if you are using eclipse, it has an inbuilt spell checker.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you can enable spell checking in Eclipse IDE (which will ignore tags and reserved keywords and apply only on your text). Maybe it can help...

The option is located in `General\Editors\Text Editors\Spelling`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IDE, spell check might already be included.

And usually for this kind of situation, properties files are used to contain the text, which allows to run the spell check on properties files only.